# H/W requirements for Confluent single node

Tags: hardware, confluent-platform, specifications

What are the hardware requirements for Single node Confluent installation?

I checked their official site, but it has specifications for multi-node: https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/system-requirements.html

Answer (score 1):

Unclear what all you're trying to run. Zookeeper and Kafka alone have been made to run with limited resources on a Raspberry Pi and definitely can run on any modern laptop or computer.

If you're running a single node, it's not considered "production grade", so with at least 5 services (ZK, broker, Schema Registry, REST proxy, ksqlDB) at 2 GB max heap each, that'd require 10 GB RAM + overhead for the OS, so call it 16 GB of memory to be conservative

If you also want to (reasonably) run Control Center, it's suggested to have 6GB for that, increasing your memory requirements up to at least 24 GB on a single node if you want to include calculation for your own Kafka client applications

Of course, you can opt out of certain services and tune each JVM to how you want...

As far as disk space goes, really depends on how much data you plan on having. 500 GB would be a good starting point, but a single disk wouldn't be fault tolerant